# How to save form to database only if content meets certain criteria

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am looking for a way to check data submitted from a form whether it meets certain criteria – not whether the data is valid, but whether, for example, a certain question is answered 'yes' or 'no', and only if the response is 'yes', should the data be saved to the database. If the submitted data does not meet the criteria, then it should not be saved to the database and a message should be displayed notifying the user.

### My code thus far:

I have a model that stores participant information:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    has_health_cover = models.CharField(
        choices=(
            ('0','No'),
            ('1','Yes)
        ), 
        default='0', 
        max_length=1
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    date_registered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

The model is created using a Modelform:

```
class ParticipantRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Participant
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'date_of_birth',
            'has_health_cover',
        ]
```

Rendered using a generic CreateView object:

```
class ParticipantRegisterView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Participant
    form_class = ParticipantRegisterForm
    template_name = 'participants/register.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.provider = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I am not sure how to go about taking the POST request data, determining whether the variable `has_health_cover` was a 0 (No) or a 1 (Yes), and to only save the data to the `Participant` database should `has_private_health == 0`.

If `has_private_health == 1` then the data should not be saved, and a flash message should appear with a message notifying the user the 'Participant is ineligible'. I have flash messages already setup in the base .html template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom [`clean_<field>`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) method to your form to check value and raise error if value is no valid:

```
class ParticipantRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Participant
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'date_of_birth',
            'has_health_cover',
        ]

    def clean_has_health_cover(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['has_health_cover']
        if data == '0':
            return data
        raise forms.ValidationError("Participant is ineligible")
```

Comment: Raising a `ValidationError` would appear as an error on the form, correct? Just like entering in a wrong password.

Comment: Is there a way to have the user redirected to another page with a flash message? Perhaps along the lines of: if data == '1': message.error(request, 'Participant is ineligible') /n return redirect('profile')

Comment: @Braden you can override view's `form_invalid` method for this.

Comment: Another solution would be to raise another (custom) exception for this exact case and catch it in the view.